# MSSQL aggregate ignoring where clause

Tags: sql-server, casting, aggregate

I have a strange problem that when performing an aggregate function on a type cast varchar column I receive an "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1. Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint." The queries where clause should filter out the non-numeric values.

Table structure is similar to this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects ao WHERE ao.name = 'Identifier' AND ao.type = 'U') BEGIN DROP TABLE Identifier END
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects ao WHERE ao.name = 'IdentifierType' AND ao.type = 'U') BEGIN DROP TABLE IdentifierType END

CREATE TABLE IdentifierType
(
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Style] [int] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_IdentifierType_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE Identifier
(
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [IdentifierTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Value] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Identifier_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE Identifier WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Identifier_IdentifierTypeID] FOREIGN KEY([IdentifierTypeID]) REFERENCES IdentifierType ([ID])
GO
```

Identifier.Value is a VARCHAR column, it can and does contain non-numeric data. Filtering the query to IdentifierType.Style = 0 should mean that 'Value' only returns string representations of integers. The query below fails with "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1. Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(Value AS BIGINT))
FROM 
  Identifier i,
  IdentifierType it
WHERE
  i.IdentifierTypeID = it.ID AND
  it.Style = 0
```

If i extend the WHERE clause to include a 'AND ISNUMERIC(i.Value) = 1' it will return the maximum integer value. That to me implies that there is a non-numeric string in my result set. Yet i get no rows returned from this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  Identifier i,
  IdentifierType it
WHERE
  i.IdentifierTypeID = it.ID AND
  it.Style = 0 AND 
  ISNUMERIC(i.Value) <> 1
```

I've been unable to identity the row(s) that are tripping the type cast. The above query should have exposed the exceptional rows. In addition, there are no empty or extremely long strings either (the largest string is 6 character long)

Is it possible that MSSQL is attempting to do the CAST on all rows rather than filtering via the WHERE clause first?

Or has anyone else seen anything similar?

There is a second work around which is instantiating the component of the query into a temp table, and then selecting the MAX value from that.

```
SELECT
  Value
INTO
  IdentifierClone
FROM 
  Identifier i,
  IdentifierType it
WHERE
  i.IdentifierTypeID = it.ID AND
  it.Style = 0

SELECT MAX(CAST(Value as BIGINT)) FROM IdentifierClone
```

A subquery doesn't work however.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) on the Connect feedback site. SQL Server sometimes jumps ahead and performs earlier conversions that raise errors that wouldn't, if it actually processed the query in the correct, logical, order, be generated.

Comment: I had some similar problem with isnumeric, trying to find not numerical values and not getting the result i expected due to isnumeric itself. If it's a problem of order try to organize with subtable to see if it's better, do your where clause in a subtable and then do your cast. You're sure it's filtered before like that.

Comment: @MatheseF - if you're referring to a subquery, you're wrong about "sure it's filtered before" - the optimizer can and *will* rearrange conversions and filtering even with subqueries, and can still produce these illogical errors. The only sure way I know of to prevent it is to split the query into two completely separate queries and have the first query populate a temp table/table variable that the second query then operates over.

Comment: Damien, thx for the information, i never had the case but probably because the optimizer hasn't reorganized my subquery, just a question of luck so can't be confident

Comment: Look at the execution plan, it will show you if any implicit conversions is happening.

Comment: I had tried the sub select approach and tripped the same error. The only way of making a sub select work was to instantiate it into a temp table. Damien, it appears you are right. Thanks for that link i'll up vote it when i get more than 30sec

Answer (score 0):

Try using a REGEX expression to find the problem record.  Here's an example where ISNUMERIC does not detect the problem but the regex expression does

```
CREATE TABLE tst (value nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO tst select '£'
-- Record found ...
SELECT * FROM tst WHERE value NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
-- No record found ...
SELECT * from tst where isnumeric(value) <> 1
```

Comment: If you meant to suggest a method of testing whether a string is convertible to an integer, the condition in your first SELECT should be `LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` (to find a value that is *not* convertible).